# Windows 10 - The numpad . opens file explorer

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, numpad

I have an odd issue with a Windows 10 PC.  When a user press the numpad period, File explorer opens.
If Numlock is turned off it does not happen, and if you press the regular period button it does not happen.
Swapping keyboards out has not fixed it either.
I manage dozens of machines and this is the only one that does it.

It is driving the user nuts.

It is a Lenovo Thin-Client running Window 10.

Any thoughts?